# looping to each record and calculate mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

First i would like to thanks all friends,i got one case which made my php program running very slow.
here's the problem,im updating new price for every item on specific branch.for example:
i got table call stock,with column -item,old price,new price,branch.i got total 3 branch stock in the same table.i would like to discount all the stock from branch call "CA".so i

```
select * from stock where branch =="CA"
```

loop and retrive old price - 20%
insert into new price

this method really consume alot of time,i got more than 5million of record.does anyone have any better solution,i really appreciate.Thanks again

Comment: The equals operator in SQL is `=` not `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do an update statement,

```
UPDATE  stock
SET     newPrice = oldPrice - (oldPrice * .2)
WHERE   branch = 'CA'
```

Answer (score 1):

Er, isn't that '0.8  * old_price'